# With handlebars.js, is it ok to call nested object properties that may be undefined?

Tags: template-engine, handlebars.js

I noticed that defining the following in my Handlebars.js templates works fine:

```
<input name="username" value="{{user.name}}">
```

This works even when:

1. user is undefined; and/or
2. user.name is undefined

However, I'm questioning how appropriate it is to do this. What's going on in the background? Wouldn't the following be more appropriate, albeit adding more cluttering?

```
<input name="username" value="{{#if user}}{{#if user.name}}{{user.name}}{{/if}}{{/if}}">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the advantage of doing it that way. This introduces more code clutter for no extra readability and no extra functionality.

So yes, if getting an undefined does not break your page, it is completely appropriate to just call it without checking if it exists.

If the non-existent content would break your page structure, however, you should definitely check to make sure it exists first.

For example, if you didn't want a comment section to show up unless there actually were comments to show, you would use the if block as you have described here.

But it would look more like this:

```
{{#if user.name}}
    <input name="username" value="{{user.name}}">
{{/if}}
```

Comment: If you want more readability, you probably meant "yes, it is appropriate to call nested object properties that may be undefined"?

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment, feedback received and answer changed :)